# Number of Sylow subgroups (another)

Tags: group-theory

if we look at $S_3$ so we have $|G|=6=3*2$

Now to find the number of Sylows subgroup we look at all the divisors of $6$ which are: $1,2,3,6$

$n_2:$ will be all the number that $2$ does not divide so it is $1,3$

$n_3:$ will be all the number that $3$ does not divide so it is $1,2$

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but you are missing the second condition, saying it is also congruent $1$ modulo $p$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde so $n_3$ is only $1$?

Comment: I would not say that it is correct to list several possibilities when the group is specified. Only one of these is the actual number.

Comment: $S_3$ has only one subgroup with three elements. So what could $n_3$ be then?